# iPhone opens applications or makes a call on its own

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4s and when I am at work and it is charging (a generic charger) it will (intermittently) open applications that are on it or makes a phone call to a contact, usually the top number in the recent calls list.  This is all without anyone touching it or instigating the action.  Has anyone else ever experienced this?

Comment: First thing I think you should try is bringing your original charger into work and using that. It is likely not the problem but I know bad power can do weird things.

Comment: It might be caused by a faulty (or dirty) touchscreen triggering false taps on random screen locations. It wouldn't be able to unlock a lock screen though, so does this behaviour persist even if the phone screen is locked?